# Задержка выполнения ASyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Всем привет!

Возникла небольшая проблема с `AsyncTask`, а именно: после первого выполнения `AsyncTask` после обновления фрагмента идет задержка около 16 секунд, и только потом происходят изменения в `UI` (т.е выполняется `onPostExecute`)

А именно это срабатывает так: я открываю фрагмент, `AsyncTask` выполняется и обновляет интерфейс (какие-то кнопки блокируются, выводится надпись о включенном сервере), нажимаю на кнопку "остановить сервис", `AsyncTask` выполняется еще раз с допустимой задержкой (около 1 секунды), я перезахожу во фрагмент, выполняется ASyncTask, я нажимаю на кнопку "Запустить сервис", перезахожу во фрагмент и все... ожидание 16 секунд, но потом все выполняется корректно.

Код `AsyncTask`:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public boolean oneperem;
}

public class third extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Wrapper> {

    private Context mContext;
    private View rootView;
    public Button startentropy, stopentropy;
    public TextView entropystatus;


    public third(Context context, View rootView) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.rootView = rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public Wrapper doInBackground(String... args) {
        final Wrapper w = new Wrapper();

        if (RootTools.isBusyboxAvailable()) {
            if (RootTools.isRootAvailable()) {
                if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {

                    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

                    Command command1 = new Command(0, "pgrep rngd") {
                        @Override
                        public void commandOutput(int id, String line) {
                            super.commandOutput(id, line);
                            latch.countDown();
                            if (line.matches("[0-9]+")) {
                                w.oneperem = true;
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void commandCompleted(int id, int exitcode) {
                            super.commandCompleted(id, exitcode);
                            latch.countDown();
                            if (exitcode == 1) {
                                w.oneperem = false;
                            }

                        }
                    };

                    try {
                        RootTools.getShell(true).add(command1);
                        try {
                            latch.await();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }

                    } catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException ex) {
                        try {
                            latch.await();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } else {

            }
        }
        else {

        }

        return w;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Wrapper w) {

                if (w.oneperem == true) {
                    entropystatus = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.entropystatus);
                    entropystatus.setText("СТАТУС СЕРВИСА: ВКЛЮЧЕН");
                    entropystatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttongood);
                    startentropy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.startentropy);
                    startentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonfuck);
                    startentropy.setEnabled(false);
                    startentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    stopentropy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stopentropy);
                    stopentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttoncal);
                    stopentropy.setEnabled(true);
                    stopentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    stopentropy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (RootTools.isBusyboxAvailable()) {
                                if (RootTools.isRootAvailable()) {
                                    if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {

                                        Command command1 = new Command(0,
                                                "entropy_disable");
                                        try {
                                            RootTools.getShell(true).add(command1);
                                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Сервис остановлен!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        } catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException ex) {
                                            ex.printStackTrace();

                                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "ОШИБКА, СВЯЖИТЕСЬ С РАЗРАБОТЧИКОМ!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "ОШИБКА!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                                else {

                                }
                            }
                            else {

                            }


                        }

                    });
                }
                if (w.oneperem == false) {
                    entropystatus = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.entropystatus);
                    entropystatus.setText("СТАТУС СЕРВИСА: ВЫКЛЮЧЕН");
                    entropystatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonbad);

                    stopentropy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stopentropy);
                    stopentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonfuck);
                    stopentropy.setEnabled(false);
                    stopentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    startentropy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.startentropy);
                    startentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttoncal);
                    startentropy.setEnabled(true);
                    startentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    startentropy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    if (RootTools.isBusyboxAvailable()) {
                                        if (RootTools.isRootAvailable()) {
                                            if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {

                                                Command command1 = new Command(0,
                                                        "entropy_enabler");
                                                try {
                                                    RootTools.getShell(true).add(command1);
                                                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Сервис запущен!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                } catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException ex) {
                                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "ОШИБКА, СВЯЖИТЕСЬ С РАЗРАБОТЧИКОМ!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "ОШИБКА!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }

                                        }
                                        else {

                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {

                                    }

                                }



                            });

                }
        }
    }
```

Код запуска ASyncTask:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle  savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entropy, parent, false);

    new third(getActivity(), view).execute();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    new third(getActivity(), getView()).execute();

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull final Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим способом: заменил использование библиотеки RootTools на нативный Runtime.execute, вынес обработчики нажатия на кнопки в отдельные ASyncTask и сделал оптимизации кода.

***Вот код всех ASyncTask и зависимых классов***

```
 public class Wrapper {
    public String oneperem;
    public boolean check;
    public boolean sucess;
}

public class third extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Wrapper> {

    private Context mContext;
    private View rootView;
    public Button startentropy, stopentropy;
    public TextView entropystatus;


    public third(Context context, View rootView) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.rootView = rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public Wrapper doInBackground(String... args) {
        final Wrapper w = new Wrapper();

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        w.oneperem = runAsRoot();

        if (w.oneperem != null && !w.oneperem.isEmpty()) {
            w.check = true;
        } else {
            w.check = false;
        }

        latch.countDown();

        return w;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Wrapper w) {

        if (w.check == true) {
            entropystatus = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.entropystatus);
            entropystatus.setText("СТАТУС СЕРВИСА: ВКЛЮЧЕН");
            entropystatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttongood);
            startentropy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.startentropy);
            startentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonfuck);
            startentropy.setEnabled(false);
            startentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            stopentropy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stopentropy);
            stopentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttoncal);
            stopentropy.setEnabled(true);
            stopentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            stopentropy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    stopentropy.setEnabled(false);

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                        new stop(getActivity(), getView()).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                    } else {
                        new stop(getActivity(), getView()).execute();
                    }
                }

            });
        }
        if (w.check == false) {
            entropystatus = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.entropystatus);
            entropystatus.setText("СТАТУС СЕРВИСА: ВЫКЛЮЧЕН");
            entropystatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonbad);

            stopentropy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stopentropy);
            stopentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonfuck);
            stopentropy.setEnabled(false);
            stopentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            startentropy = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.startentropy);
            startentropy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttoncal);
            startentropy.setEnabled(true);
            startentropy.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            startentropy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startentropy.setEnabled(false);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                        new start(getActivity(), getView()).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                    } else {
                        new start(getActivity(), getView()).execute();
                    }
                }

            });

        }
    }
}

public class stop extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Wrapper> {

    private Context mContext;
    private View rootView;

    public stop(Context context, View rootView) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.rootView = rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public Wrapper doInBackground(String... args) {
        final Wrapper w1 = new Wrapper();

        final CountDownLatch latch3 = new CountDownLatch(1);

        try {
            Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

            outputStream.writeBytes("entropy_disable\n");
            outputStream.flush();
            w1.sucess = true;
            outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
            outputStream.flush();
            latch3.countDown();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            w1.sucess = false;
        }

        return w1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Wrapper w1) {

        if (w1.sucess == true) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Сервис остановлен!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "ОШИБКА, СВЯЖИТЕСЬ С РАЗРАБОТЧИКОМ!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}

public class start extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Wrapper> {

    private Context mContext;
    private View rootView;

    public start(Context context, View rootView) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.rootView = rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public Wrapper doInBackground(String... args) {
        final Wrapper w2 = new Wrapper();

        final CountDownLatch latch2 = new CountDownLatch(1);

        try {
            Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

            outputStream.writeBytes("entropy_enabler\n");
            outputStream.flush();
            w2.sucess = true;
            outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
            outputStream.flush();
            latch2.countDown();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            w2.sucess = false;
        }
        return w2;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Wrapper w2) {

        if (w2.sucess == true) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Сервис запущен!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "ОШИБКА, СВЯЖИТЕСЬ С РАЗРАБОТЧИКОМ!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}

public String runAsRoot() {

    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pgrep rngd");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        int read;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.append(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        reader.close();

        process.waitFor();

        return output.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

***И вызов ASyncTask***

```
 if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
        new third(getActivity(), view ).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    } else {
        new third(getActivity(), view ).execute();
    }
```

Comment: Неплохой рефакторинг не помешал, верно?)

Comment: @ Asgard конечно! верно!

Comment: @Asgard а кстати не знаете случайно как сделать переносы текста в пунктах Navigation Drawer?)

Comment: как понять переносы текста?

Comment: @Asgard ну например в Navigation Drawer есть пункт "Советы по улучшению энергосбережения". В пункт Navigation Drawer этот текст не влезает и отображается как "Советы по улучшению". Вот и хотел сделать перенос текста в пункте, ну аналог \n в TextView

Answer (score 2):

Для начала давайте попробуем вспомнить жизненный цикл фрагмента, и вот что происходит при его запуске:

```
onAttach
onCreate
onCreateView
onActivityCreated
onStart
onResume
```

В таком порядке вызываются методы. Смотрим на ваш код, в котором видим следующее:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle  savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entropy, parent, false);

    new third(getActivity(), view).execute();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    new third(getActivity(), getView()).execute();

}
```

За одно включение фрагмента, вы создаете два экземпляра AsyncTask'a, учитывая, что у вас не установлен `setRetainInstance()` , при повороте фрагмента все заново пересоздается - что еще больше усугубляет ситуацию. И каждый раз вы имеете по 2 создания AsyncTask.

Попробуйте для начала установить в `onCreateView()` метод `setOnRetainInstance(true)`, лишним не будет.

Затем удалите из `onResume()` создание второго объекта AsyncTask'a, напишите результат.

Comment: Спасибо! Пытаюсь добавить данный параметр, но Android Studio пишет: Error:(53, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setOnRetainInstance(boolean)
И еще, если убрать из onResume(), то повторное выполнение будет возвращать не верный результат

Comment: `setOnRetainInstance(true)` вам нужно сделать в `onCreateView()` , мне не понятно, почему повторное выполнение будет возвращать не верный результат.
После поворота экрана, имеете ввиду?

Comment: @NowenUI кстати в этом фрагменте кода `catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException ex)` у вас неправильное условие "Или".
Логическое условие "или" двумя прямыми линиями обозначаются ||. То есть выглядеть будет так: `catch (IOException || RootDeniedException || TimeoutException ex)`

Comment: Я его и добавлял в onCreateView() после инициализации лейута, не может найти метод. Насчёт onResume, смотрите: у меня в OnBackGround проверяется служба, запущена или нет и в onPostExecute TextView отображает соответствующее сообщение. Если добавить строчку в onResume, то повторное выполнение ASyncTask выдаёт верный результат (например, если служба в реальности запущена, то сначала мигнёт "Служба не запущена", а потом выдаст верное сообщение). Если строчки в onResume нет, то при повторном выполнение выдаёт неверный результат (служба не запущена, а в реальности запущена)

Comment: В Java есть и оператор `| ` и оператор `||`. Оператор `|` всегда проверяют значение обоих операндов. Оператор `||` называется оператор короткой схемы, в этом случае, если результат булевого выражения может быть определён из левого операнда, правый операнд не вычисляется.

Comment: @Asgard 
Опечатка была, setOnRetainInstance(true) такого метода нет, а вот setRetainInstance() есть, его добавил (true), изменений никаких

Comment: @Asgard вот видеодемонстрация: https://yadi.sk/i/VUDtkZ_utkKD5

Comment: @pavlofff препод в универе говорил, что нельзя использовать | одну для подобных условий, ибо для операций битовых. Так и рушится вера :D

Comment: @NowenUI дружище, тогда не знаю если честно даже.

Comment: @Asgard :( Я вот тоже не понимаю, в чем проблема, вроде бы все корректно написано, а работает непонятно...   А насчет | я думаю у меня корректно, так как  это код из wiki  библиотеки RootTools от её автора, не думаю что сам автор допустит такую оплошность

Comment: @Asgard все-таки решил проблему)

Comment: @Asgard http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/549942/200672
задержка и некорректное выполнение ASyncTask, теперь все выполняется быстро и без задержек